# How to filter tasks from include statement

Tags: ansible

Currently, I would pass a parameter to include and use that variable in another file to check conditionally which block to execute.

eg,

```
- include: tasks/common.yml param=dns
```

tasks/common.yml:

```
---
- block:
  - name: do something interesting
    when: param == "dns"
- block:
  - name: do another thing
    when: param == "ip"
```

This method works however in my output all the tasks that don't match the condition are displayed as skipping. Since I have dozens of tasks and try to reuse some of them I see a lot of skipping tasks.

Is there a better way doing this? Using ansible 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for that in the playbook or in ansible parameters. One way is to configure your ansible to not display skipped tasks.

See: [stdout_callback](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#stdout-callback)

> New in version 2.0.
>
> This setting allows you to override the default stdout callback for
>   ansible-playbook:
>
> stdout_callback = skippy

Edit your ansible config file (usually `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`) and add this line under `defaults` section

```
stdout_callback = skippy
```

which tells ansible not to display skipped tasks.

Before setting to `skippy`

```
TASK [Run scripts] *************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=1)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=2)
```

After setting to `skippy`

```
TASK [Run scripts] *************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=1)
```